# Node Webkit - Options for encoding in writeFileSync not work?

Tags: node.js, encoding, node-webkit, nw.js

I am a beginner.

I want to write an HTML file containing Chinese characters in UTF8 encoding. I found the following code from the internet.

```
fs.writeFileSync(target, generateHTML(), "utf8");
```

Though when I read the documentation, it didn't explicitly say I can add an encoding flag. `generateHTML()` returns the HTML string.

However, the following characters "返回" became something like this: "æ´»å‹•" in the file. I am sure that it is an encoding error.

Am I using the wrong function? How can I write a file in sync using proper utf-8?

---

### EDIT

The `fs.writeFileSync` worked alone well, but not when the content is returned as a function. Please try this:

```
function generateHTML(){return "返回"}
fs.writeFileSync("index.html", generateHTML(), "utf8");
```

The file contains `ԏ` in utf-8 format, which is not the intended content.

---

### EDIT

I tested this with my installed node.js version and it was working properly. It seems to have something to do with node webkit.

I'll include the version later. The time here is not convenient for me.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in the first place? What encoding has the text returned by generateHTML()? As far as I know, node.js uses utf8 for text internally, so the command you use would just pass through whatever the function returns unaltered.

Comment: @mthierer I want the utf-8 string to be stored the same in a utf-8 encoded file. However, my resulted file is also stored in utf-8 format but the text is unreadable possibly because of a failed encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to set the working node-webkit application page to have a utf-8 encoding. I have to add this to the page:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

It turns out to be something very simple yet I've missed.

Answer (score 0):

This is working well for me:

```
fs.writeFileSync('test.html', '返回', 'utf8');
```

Comment: Yes I think you have something weird in `generateHTML()`

Comment: please see my edit. please try making `'返回'` as a returned string from a function

Comment: I got this using node-webkit. I tested with my installed node.js using cmd and it is indeed working. Should I delete this post?